# AJAX Express receive array on client

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, express, web-development-server

I am having trouble with receiving array data as it flows from another source into my client. My goal is to have the HTML document populate with data from the array as it is received by the server.

Server:

```
const keywordsList = [];

const keywordsListSerialize = JSON.stringify(keywordsList);
const arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, keywordsList))
// const keywordsListObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);

app.use(cors())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // res.writeHead(200, {
  //     'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  //     'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
  //     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  //   });
    //res.flushHeaders();
    res.send(keywordsList);
    //res.write(arrayToString);
  //res.status(200).send(arrayToString);
  //res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' })
});
```

As you can see from the server code, I have tried multiple variations of sending data as a JSON object/just an array or a string and I can't seem to get ANY of it to even show up on my client.

Client:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xhttp);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText)
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      for(i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("keywordsList").innerHTML = jsonObj;
      }
    }
  };
xhttp.open("GET", "/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

The client does two very basic but interesting things. 1. the xhttp.responseText is the whole HTML file which makes me think I should be handling the request somehow in my server (I figured I could get away with just constantly streaming data to the client) and 2. Sends me an error

`VM812:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange`

I believe I am having multiple issues. I understand that I will want to send data almost definitely as a JSON object and parse it on the client but at the most basic examples, I can't even get that to work. I have double checked that how I have my client and server setup is correct and if need be, I can discuss how it's setup as to make sure they are linked correctly locally.

I am looking for guidance as well as possibly a technical answer. Please do not just link me ajax documentation because I have probably read it 3 times over (minimum) at this point. I thought of just throwing everything away and using a websocket as it would accomplish what I am trying to achieve but that means learning all of that.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const keywordsList = ['apple', 'banana', 'cucumber']
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(keywordsList))
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Testing the web server:

```
curl http://localhost:3000

["apple","banana","cucumber"]
```

To iterate over the response in the client:

```
const arrayOnClientSide = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
arrayOnClientSide.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

which outputs:

```
apple
banana
cucumber
```

Note that every time you call `.innerHTML` you will overwrite whatever value it previously held, so construct the presentation format of your display value first, then assign it to `innerHTML` at the end.

Comment: Say I pass nothing into the array to start, shouldn't I be getting an empty array in the console on the client? I've gotten [object Object] before but I can't remember how right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this never worked for me. I still don't get what is wrong with my setup. I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: keywordsList.forEach is not a function.

I believe I have an error in how the web server and my client are setup and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out eventually. The only post above from someone else is correct. It's that simple to send data across. Unfortunately, when trying to understand AJAX and express at the same time, you get confused on whether you are really sending data AND if that data is structured correctly so the client doesn't just throw out errors. I was conflating AJAX and express issues together which could have been resolved quicker had I understood how to correctly test stuff but alas, I am by myself working this all out.

For any poor sap who might come across this, probably don't use XMLHttpRequests and just use JQuery.

Thanks for the response.